# Add range to an array with JSON_MODIFY

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add an array to another array using `JSON_MODIFY`.
The situation is, I have an array kind stored json data in database. It looks like this:

```sql
declare @base nvarchar(max) = '[{"name":"base"}]';
```

And I am getting another set of data which is also in the shape of array:

```sql
declare @test1 nvarchar(max) = '[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"example1"}]';
```

I am trying to use `JSON_MODIFY` and `JSON_QUERY` magics to append them together but it gives me unexpected results.

```sql
declare @base nvarchar(max) = '[{"name":"base"}]';
declare @test1 nvarchar(max) = '[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"example1"}]';
set @base = JSON_MODIFY(@base,'append $',JSON_QUERY(@test1));
select @base;
```

Output:

```
[{"name":"base"}, [{"name":"test1"},{"name":"example1"}]]
```

But what I want is using those methods to make it work like kind of `Add-Range`:

```
[{"name":"base"},{"name":"test1"},{"name":"example1"}]
```

I am kind of lost on this process and I don't know where to look at for this kind of functionality.
I will use this from a C# service to directly modify through the code. That's why I cannot use Store procedures and functions as well.

> Edit #1:

With regarding to reply from @Salman A, i appreciate your answer but the thing is, as i said earlier, it is a little bit difficult to use on my query running through code. Which is:

```
declare @test1 nvarchar(max) = '[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"example1"}]';
UPDATE dbo.ExampleTable 
   SET [Data] = JSON_MODIFY([Data], 'append $', JSON_QUERY(@test1))
   WHERE [UniqueId] = 'some_guid_here'
```

I have tried it to adapt the answer that i like this :

```
declare @test1 nvarchar(max) = '[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"example1"}]';
UPDATE dbo.ExampleTable 
   SET [Data] = (
      select [Data] = JSON_MODIFY([Data],'append $',item)
      from OPENJSON(@test1)
      with ([item] nvarchar(max) '$' as JSON)
   )
   WHERE [UniqueId] = 'some_id'
```

Actually, it works if `@test1` only have 1 item, but in case of having more than 1 item in `@test1`, it gives the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows = .....

What is the logical way to use this in a `update set subquery`

Comment: Which SQL-Server version? Are you open for dealing with this on string level?

Comment: SQL Server 14. I would rather not to dive into string level. It will be a command calling from C# code. I could deal with the string on that level as well. But I prefer not to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `OPENJSON` to convert the array to rows and append items one by one:

```sql
declare @base nvarchar(max) = '[{"name":"base"}]';
declare @test1 nvarchar(max) = '[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"example1"}]';

select @base = json_modify(@base, 'append $', item)
from openjson(@test1)
with ([item] nvarchar(max) '$' as json);

select @base;
```

Returns:

```
[{"name":"base"},{"name":"test1"},{"name":"example1"}]
```

**Revised answer for update query**

If you're using SQL Server 2017+ then a reasonably safe solution is to concatenate the array using `STRING_AGG` but build individual rows using JSON functions. It is relatively easy to use this idea in an update query:

```
DECLARE @base NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"name":"base"}]';
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"foo":"bar"},{"baz":"meh"}]';

SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG(jsonstr, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pos) + ']'
FROM (
    SELECT value, 1000 + [key] FROM OPENJSON(@base)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value, 2000 + [key] FROM OPENJSON(@test)
) AS x(jsonstr, pos);
```

Alternately, you can use a recursive CTE that calls `JSON_MODIFY` multiple times to build the JSON; you can use the result in update query:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    data NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO t(data) VALUES
('[{"name":"1.1"}]'),
('[{"name":"2.1"},{"name":"2.2"}]');

WITH rows(data, pos) AS (
    SELECT value, [key]
    FROM OPENJSON('[{"foo":"bar"},{"baz":"meh"}]')
), rcte(id, data, pos) AS (
    SELECT id, data, -1
    FROM t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT prev.id, JSON_MODIFY(prev.data, 'append $', JSON_QUERY(curr.data)), prev.pos + 1
    FROM rcte AS prev
    JOIN rows AS curr ON curr.pos = prev.pos + 1
)
UPDATE t
SET data = (
    SELECT TOP 1 data
    FROM rcte
    WHERE id = t.id
    ORDER BY pos DESC
);
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=058ec0c1710f9e282f32e4e303d9e8cb)

Comment: And if you don't like that, you can keep what you have and [flatten](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/242662/5203) the result as the last step.

Comment: Consider the keys are not known. Mine was just an example. It processes through a generic queue system. Keys could be anything and they could not be at the same structure as well. `{"name" : "some"}` is one of them, but the other one would be `{"id" : 1241, "amount" : 24}`

Comment: I'll revert to the original answer then. But I am not sure how `SELECT @foo = col` works if there is more then 1 row.

Comment: Keep the original i would say, yet, it is only a start point for me to get the solution. I still did not get the proper solution for my question tho.

Comment: It should work with arbitrary JSON as-is. There is an alternate using recursive cte https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=72a0f42ce7cb651f14cc58803a20e2b3